# Intellisense not updating in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, intellisense

**Given:**
A table named `Table1` that has the following columns:

- `ID`
- `ColumnA`
- `ColumnB`

Typing `Table1.` in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio provides me with a list of columns for that table.

**Scenario:**

I open up `Table1` in the design view and add `ColumnC` to it. I save `Table1` and refresh it to see the new column, `Column3` show up in the Object Explorer.

Going back to the Query Window, I type `Table1.` but `Column3` is not available to be selected. Typing it out gives me a syntax error but running a query with the column in it works as expected.

Is there a menu item somewhere that I need to click to get Intellisense to pick up the DDL changes I have made?

Comment: Would you explain more or copy the error here? You mean when you run `SELECT * FROM tabel1` you dont see the Column3 at all?

Comment: No.  The problem is that intellisense doesn't recognize the new column until the cache is refreshed.  You can still type in the column and get good results but you get the squiggly red line.

Comment: BTW, I agree that refreshing the table or database seems intuitively like it should do this automatically.  I'm curious if anyone knows of a good reason it doesn't or if it's just an oversight.

Comment: Knowing Microsoft its probably an oversight. :P

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Edit -> Intellisense - Refresh Local Cache

That should do it.

Ctrl-Shift-R is the shortcut.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to refreshing the cache you also need to do the following if you haven't already:

Go to Tools >> Options >> Text Editor >> Transact-SQL >> General >> IntelliSense

Check the box Auto List Members and also the box Parameter Information save and restart.

I also highly recommend the Redgate SQL Toolbox if you regularly use SQL Server.  SQL Compare and SQL Data Compare and the SQL Prompt5 have saved me lots of time in development.

Answer (score 0):

I have to restart management studio when this happens. Refreshing object explorer doesn't update the intellisense.

Comment: check out the accepted answer. You won't have to do that anymore ;-)